# $f$ continuous in $[0,2]$, $f(0) = f(2)$. Prove that $x_0 \in [0,1]$ exists such as that $f(x_0)=f(x_0+1)$

Tags: functions, continuity

$f$ is a continuous function in $[0,2]$

Let $f(0) = f(2)$

How can I prove that $x_0 \in [0,1]$ exists such as that $f(x_0)=f(x_0+1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the intermediate value theorem to $g:[0,1]$ defined by $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, $g(0)=f(1)-f(0)$, $g(1)=f(2)-f(1)=f(0)-f(1)$ have opposite signs., thus there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ $g(x_0)=f(x_0+1)-f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: I understand that $g(0), g(1)$ have opposite signs, but didn't understand what you did next

Comment: I apply the intermediate value theorem: $g(0)\leq 0, g(1)\geq 0$ implies there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ with $g(x_0)=0$. and if $g(0)\geq 0$ and $g(1)\leq 0$, the intermediate value theorem implies there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ with $g(x_0)=0$. One the situation above is realized since $g(0)$ and $g(1)$ have opposite sign.

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant. Just for the formality, how can I say for sure that $g$ is continuous? It needs to be in order to use the intermediate value theorem

Comment: In French, the particular case of intermediate value you use (say $g(0)<0, g(1)>0 \implies g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0 \in (0,1)$) is called by a funny name: "théorème du passage des douanes" ("customs' crossing theorem"). I don't know if, in other languages, there is an equivalent...

Comment: @S.Peter $g(x)$ is continuous because $f(x)$ and $f(x+1)$ both are.